# How to add depended form field in magento admin

Tags: admin, adminhtml, adminform

I am not so familiar with magento so i am facing some trouble
I am creating a form in magento admin & trying to add depended form field
eg- parent field is dropdown type & name is `amount_type` options are `flat_option` & `percentage_option`

child field are text type having name `flat_value` & `percentage_value`

So my requirment `flat_value` & `percentage_value` are hidden at first after that if i select `flat_option` in `amount_type` then show `flat_value` & in select `percentage_option` then show `percentage_option`.

my tried code is

```
$fieldset->addField('amount_type', 'select', array(
            'name' => 'amount_type',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Amount Type'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Amount Type'),
            'class' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'value'     => '1',
    'values'    => array('-1'=>'Please Select','1' => 'flat_option', '2' => 'percentage_option'),
                )
        );

$fieldset->addField('flat_value', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'flat_value',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('flat amount'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('flat amount'),
            'class' => 'validate-number',
            'required' => true,
                )
        );

$fieldset->addField('percentage_value', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'percentage_value',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Percentage amount'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Percentage amount'),
            'class' => 'validate-number validate-digits-range digits-range-0-100',
            'required' => true,
                )
        );

$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap('amount_type', 'amount_type')
        ->addFieldMap('flat_value', 'flat_value)
        ->addFieldDependence('flat_value', 'amount_type', 1)
);

$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap('amount_type', 'amount_type')
        ->addFieldMap('percentage_value', 'percentage_value')
        ->addFieldDependence('percentage_value', 'amount_type', 2)
);
```

Tanks in advance for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below code

```
$accountField = $fieldset->addField('amount_type', 'select', array(
            'name' => 'amount_type',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Amount Type'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Amount Type'),
            'class' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'value'     => '1',
    'values'    => array('-1'=>'Please Select','1' => 'flat_option', '2' => 'percentage_option'),
                )
        );

$flatField = $fieldset->addField('flat_value', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'flat_value',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('flat amount'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('flat amount'),
            'class' => 'validate-number',
            'required' => true,
                )
        );

$presentageField = $fieldset->addField('percentage_value', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'percentage_value',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Percentage amount'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Percentage amount'),
            'class' => 'validate-number validate-digits-range digits-range-0-100',
            'required' => true,
                )
        );

$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap($accountField->getHtmlId(), $accountField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($flatField->getHtmlId(), $flatField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($presentageField->getHtmlId(), $presentageField->getName())
         ->addFieldDependence(
                $presentageField->getName(),
                $accountField->getName(),
                2
            )
            ->addFieldDependence(
                $flatField->getName(),
                $accountField->getName(),
                1
            )
);
```

Refer this [**Link**](http://www.atwix.com/magento/fields-dependency-in-magento-admin-forms/) you will get better understanding of field dependency

Comment: tried this on Magento ver. 1.9.3.10 didn't work at all but perhaps it's our cms doing something bad

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaram R pls can you answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281435/magento-2-add-custom-tab-in-customer-edit-section-and-save-data