# In Magento 2, How to use multiple dependencies for admin form

Tags: adminform, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I want to use the `select` and `text` fields. That fields should show based on the another `select` (dropdown) values.

ie., if value 1 means, should show `select` field, if the value 2 means, should show `text` field.

[Magento 1 working ref](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73965/how-to-add-depended-form-field-in-magento-admin).

Here is my code:

`$selectField = $fieldset->addField('publish-type','select',
            [
                'name' => 'merchant-type',
                'label' => __('Publish To'),
                'title' => __('Publish To'),
                'required' => false,
                'options' => $selectType
            ]);
    $hideField =  $fieldset->addField('merchant-type', 'select', ['name' => 'merchants-mail-id', 'label' => __('Enter Merchants Mail ids'),
        'options' => $merchantgroupArray]
        );
    $merchantsMail = $fieldset->addField('merchants-mail-id', 'textarea', ['name' => 'merchants-mail-id', "readonly" => "true", 'label' => __('Enter Merchants Mail ids')]);`

```
$dependence = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence')
        ->addFieldMap($selectField->getHtmlId(), $selectField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($hideField->getHtmlId(), $hideField->getName())
        ->addFieldDependence($hideField->getName(),$selectField->getName(),1);

    $mailDependence = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence')
        ->addFieldMap($selectField->getHtmlId(), $selectField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($merchantsMail->getHtmlId(), $merchantsMail->getName())
        ->addFieldDependence($merchantsMail->getName(),$selectField->getName(),2);
    $this->setChild('form_after', $dependence);
    $this->setChild('form_after', $mailDependence);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the same M1 format is working. I missed form id and name.

```
$selectField = $fieldset->addField('send-to','select',['name' => '**send-to**','label' => __('Publish To'),'title' => __('Publish To'),'required' => true,'options' => $selectType]);
$hideField =  $fieldset->addField('merchant-type', 'select', ['name' => 'merchant-type', 'required' => true,'label' => __('Select Merchant Type'),'options' => $merchantgroupArray]);
$merchantsMail = $fieldset->addField('merchants-mail-id', 'textarea', ['name' => 'merchants-mail-id','required' => true, 'label' => __('Enter Merchants Mail ids')]
    );
$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence')
        ->addFieldMap($selectField->getHtmlId(), $selectField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($hideField->getHtmlId(), $hideField->getName())
        ->addFieldMap($merchantsMail->getHtmlId(), $merchantsMail->getName())
        ->addFieldDependence($merchantsMail->getName(),$selectField->getName(),2)
        ->addFieldDependence($hideField->getName(),$selectField->getName(),1)
    );
    $fieldset->addField('send-comments', 'textarea', ['name' => 'send-comments', "readonly" => "true", 'label' => __('Enter Comments')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the same issue already reported in Magento [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4796#issue-157674939)

Maybe you will find your solution there.

Already **srenon** has mentioned how to pass multiple dependencies using **addFieldDependence**, please check there.

Check this.

Possible solution without editing core would be to create a DI for \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Dependency\FieldFactory $_fieldFactory then

```
    $refField = $this->_fieldFactory->create(
         ['fieldData' => ['value' => 'dependecy 1,dependecy 2', 'separator' => ','], 'fieldPrefix' => '']
    );

   .......
    ->addFieldDependence
     (
       $field_to_show->getName(),
       $field_to_evaluate->getName(),
       $refField
      )
```

Comment: @Hits, This is the code to show the fields for value 1 and 2 both, not separate fields.